# Listbox keeps repeating first items

Tags: windows-10, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple listbox that loads items (in my test case 135). 
I logged all the ID's of the items that are loaded, and they all have a unique ID. The listbox datatemplate is a usercontrol, so in the usercontrol I also logged the ID's to see which ones are loaded.

Now is where it starts going wrong, it only loads about the first 10 items (I think whatever is initially visible), and then keeps repeating those first items over and over again. So instead of 135 unique objects, I have 135 objects that are one of the first 10 or so loaded.

You can see the logging here (there are a lot more ID's not visible):

[image]

After the User Control ID's line, that's the only ID's it loads and keeps looping those 10 ID's until there are 135 items in the listbox.

This is the full page code

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="3">

                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SearchBox x:Name="sbSearch" QuerySubmitted="sbSearch_QuerySubmitted" Margin="12,12,12,0"></SearchBox>


        <ListBox x:Name="lbResults" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" Background="{x:Null}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <userControls:WantlistItem Tag="{Binding}"></userControls:WantlistItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit1: Loading of listbox in main page

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Variables.WantsAll == null) Helpers.GetWantList();
        foreach (var v in Variables.WantsAll)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(v.id);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("--- USER CONTROL ID's ---");
        lbResults.ItemsSource = Variables.WantsAll;


    }
```

In the UserControl Page_Loaded I'm logging them as well.

In this screenshot you can see I scrolled down, and it starts repeating the same items again (sometimes it messes up, as you can see the first item is not correctly repeated, it's a different one).

Note that in front of the names I added the ID's it prints out, you can see it's repeating the same ID's (for example the green album: 1301162), even tho in the list I set as ItemsSource it only exists once (all items are unique).

[image: Scroll down]

Comment: How do you print the ids? In which event of which control?

Comment: I edited the first post with the logging of the ID's. It happens in the Page_Loaded of the main page and in the user control as well (that are the ones you see after "--- USER CONTROL ID's ---")

Comment: Can you share more details on the " Helpers.GetWantList()" and "Variables.WantsAll"? what types are they? Additionally, can you try a simple test where you bind, or assign lbResults.ItemsSource to a List<> or IEnumerable<>. The listbox is indeed using virtualization so if your WantsAll object does not implement IEnumerable properly that what would happen.

Comment: It might be something with template. Try to use standard template for ListBoxItem

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? As @AlexDrenea said, this may related to the virtualization of ListBox. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088429/virtualisation-not-changing-properties-of-new-visible-items) is a similar case may help you.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, yes that case solved it precisely. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know it helps. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment provided by [Jay Zuo - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5506161/jay-zuo-msft) provided the solution, the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088429/virtualisation-not-changing-properties-of-new-visible-items) solved my problem exactly.